# Debugging macro that utilizes memory and frees in it?

Tags: c, pointers, macros, c-preprocessor, heap-memory

I have written a debugging macro and wished to include the time in it, in this case my function `gettimestr()` accepts a small buffer (always 8 in length, because its `sprintf` pads to `00:00:00`) and include that with the `fprintf` within. My macro looks like the following:

```
#define _DEBUGPRINT(...)    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define WHERESTR  "[[%s] file %s, line %d]: "
#  define WHEREARG  timebufstr_0, __FILE__, __LINE__
#  define DEBUGPRINT(_fmt, ...) \
          char timebufstr_0[8]; \
          gettimestr( timebufstr_0 );\
          _DEBUGPRINT(WHERESTR _fmt, WHEREARG, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#  define DEBUGPRINT(_fmt, ...)  /**/
#endif
```

My first attempt was to have `gettimestr` return a `const char*`, but that is hard to free memory of so I went ahead and used a buffer if you can see.

Unfortunately the buffer cannot be used twice (two DEBUGPRINTs will give a redeclaration error) and also I believe it won't free the memory because it will disappear when main returns, as it is not in a function?

My questions are:

- Should I `malloc()` 8 bytes (or 9 if
  for \0, I am unaware if that is
  required now) instead of [8] so I can
  free it on demand in the heap?
- How should I be able to create the
  buffer, destroy references, and reuse
  it in another macro call to fix my
  problem where I could not call it
  twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define _DEBUGPRINT(...)    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define WHERESTR  "[[%s] file %s, line %d]: "
#  define WHEREARG  timebufstr_0, __FILE__, __LINE__
#  define DEBUGPRINT(_fmt, ...) \
   do { \
      char timebufstr_0[8]; \
      gettimestr( timebufstr_0 );\
      _DEBUGPRINT(WHERESTR _fmt, WHEREARG, __VA_ARGS__) \
   } while (0);
#else
#  define DEBUGPRINT(_fmt, ...)  /**/
#endif
```

Will allow multiple uses and deallocate the buffer after each use.

Comment: Well, to be accurate, the buffer probably won't be deallocated, but it will probably be reused by the next call with any halfway reasonable compiler. The buffer space will be reclaimed when the function exits.

Comment: This works excellently, and now I've written my first useful complex macro!

Comment: One note, you forgot to put a closing bracket before the while `} while (0);`

Comment: The `do { ... } while(0)` should not have a trailing `;`, since it should be possible to use it as `if (foo) DEBUGPRINT(...); else ...`.

Comment: @Lindydancer: You're right. I usually leave off the trailing ;. In his example it looked as if he expected the semicolon as part of the macro.

Comment: I simply love the input, more to think about in the usage scenarios. Than you guys.

Comment: Good! This a useful way to do things like this. (Don't get me started with gcc statement expressions :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate 9 bytes for including the `'\0'` byte. The best way is to make it via a an array as posted in your code. For overcomming the problems of double-definition, you can enclose it in `{}`, e.g.:

```
#define _DEBUGPRINT(...)    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define WHERESTR  "[[%s] file %s, line %d]: "
#  define WHEREARG  timebufstr_0, __FILE__, __LINE__
#  define DEBUGPRINT(_fmt, ...) \
          {\ // <---------
          char timebufstr_0[9]; \
          gettimestr( timebufstr_0 );\
          _DEBUGPRINT(WHERESTR _fmt, WHEREARG, __VA_ARGS__)\
          } // <---------
#else
#  define DEBUGPRINT(_fmt, ...)  /**/
#endif
```

Comment: You really need `do { ... } while (0)` for this kind of macro, otherwise it will break when used between an `if` and an `else`.

Comment: Thank you for warning me about the null byte and a bit more about the idea!